# Looking for an explanation about containerd-shim/runc child processes

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, ps, runc, containerd

We are using docker within a swarm environnement.
Everything is fine... but for a strange process named "exe" that appeared, a few days ago :

```
14126 root      20   0  446836  33648    184 R  49.0  0.2   0:05.98 exe
    1 root      20   0   52356    532    332 S  34.3  0.0   2750:22 systemd
13789 root      20   0 5424660  49784      0 S   5.6  0.3   2381:57 dockerd
```

It did take up to 100% of the CPU.
We tried to understand where it came from, but it was very volatile, and its pid changed every 3-4s.
You can guess that such a behaviour triggered a few alarms.
Eventually, we set up a few monitoring tools (using auditd) to take a snapshot of it, and saw that :

```
Syscall event   curl    /usr/bin/curl   24242   24234
Syscall event   4       /               24240   24234
Syscall event   exe     /usr/bin/runc   24240   24234
Syscall event   runc    /usr/bin/runc   24234   10444
```

The parent process of the "main" runc is :

```
root 10444 2621 0 Nov13 ? 00:07:07 containerd-shim
```

I read a few things (including [this one](http://alexander.holbreich.org/docker-components-explained/) and [that other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58817768/how-does-containerd-shim-create-daemonless-containers), and many more) about containerd-shim and runc... I think I understand runc is used to launch demonless containers, and then containerd-shim takes over as the container process' parent .
Thus, I understand why I see briefly runc as containerd-shim' child process everytime a container is started.

But there are still a few things that still escape me :

- why are there are several levels of runc (one runc calling another)?
- why is it not called "runc" but "exe", and thus looking very suspicious (when it sounds like it is legitimate)?  Is it the mainprocess of the container (or another one)?
- what is this strange process called "4" and whose executable path is "/"? Is it part of the processes in the container (or the main one)?
- I guess the curl is the healthcheck performed in the container (it's an apache container with a healtcheck targeting localhost). Am I right?
- Provided the main process of the container is not the "4" one, should I see it and how could I see it in a similar way?

In the meantime, the process has just stopped using the whole cpu. It appears brievely (but sounds legitimate) every time a container is started, but does not take more than a few percents. So I think the excessive CPU usage of it was related to some problem in our container. Anyway, solving the problem of cpu was not my point here.

**Edit 1 :**

**About dockerfiles**

There are a lot of container running on the VM, and I can't provide all Dockerfiles.
The one I suspect is triggering the curl through healthcheck is an apache httpd (centOs Based) image.
It is very close to the [CentOS one](https://github.com/CentOS/CentOS-Dockerfiles/blob/master/httpd/centos7/Dockerfile) with mainly some labeling, cleaning (unused modules), and an additionnal healthckeck:

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=3s CMD curl --noproxy '*' --fail http://localhost:80/ || exit 1
```

**About monitoring**

we are using [rsyslog](https://www.rsyslog.com/) with a basic conf targeting a remote server, and then launch auditctl to monitor process triggering :

```
service rsyslog restart
service auditd start
auditctl -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S execve -F key=procmon
```

Comment: (3) seems interesting, could you provide the details about how did you observe it? (4) is probably true, but requires the exact `Dockerfile` for verification.

Comment: about (4), I can't tell exactly which container triggered that one cause we have a lot of containers running on this VM (and some sometimes restart because of maintenance on machines) . I will add a few exemples but they will not cover all our running containers I will also add some explanation about how we monitored that.

Comment: I would suggest splitting item (3) ("why does process called '4' appears in the audit log during the container start?") into the separate question, as the complete answer to all of the points of current post is pretty long overall, and on the other hand (3) seems to be a self-sufficient topic and is not directly related to `runc` itself, but rather to the behavior of `exec` under some circumstances, happening in `runc` at some specific stage of initialization.

Comment: Item (2) could also be moved into the same question as (3), as it is somewhat related to the same topic ("strange" names of the processes - why do they appear and what do they mean).

Comment: Sounds a good suggestion. I will follow it asap